# Rank php multidimensional array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, rank

I'm trying to rank a group of scores. So I've taken the input from a users form and sorted them from largest to smallest in a multidimensional array, so then that I can search the array for the user and retrieve the index to get its "rank" however I appear to be doing something totally wrong! any help on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated, or if there is a better way entirely!

Thank you

PHP Code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $size = $num_rows;
    $p = 0;
    $myarray = array();

    while ( $p < $size ) {
        $myarray[] = array( "user" => $user[$p], "data" => $scanrate[$p] );
        $p++;
    }

    $sort = array();

    foreach ( $myarray as $k => $v ) {
        $sort['data'][$k] = $v['data'];
    }

    array_multisort( $sort['data'], SORT_DESC, $myarray );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $key = array_search( $i, array_column( $myarray, 'user' ) );

        if ( !$key ) {
            $key = $num_rows;
        }
        //this is stored into my database
        echo "<br>User " . $user[$i] . " scan rate " . $scanrate[$i] . " rank " . $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: _" I appear to be doing something totally wrong! "_ Mind telling us what that is?

Answer (score 0):

You do useless code to do this sort, use the usort() function like :

```
while($p < $size)  
{ 
  $myarray[] = array("user" => $user[$p], "data" => $scanrate[$p]); 
  $p++; 
} 

usort($myarray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['data'] - $b['data'];
});
```

Now your $myarray is sorted and you can search and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting too much effort on smt. with a scripting language, you're definitely doing it wrong...

```
$sort = array_combine($user, $scanrate);
asort($sort);

// $sort is sorted now, used it as you like:

// List them
foreach ($sort as $user => $scanrate) {
    echo "<br>User " . $user . " scan rate " . $scanrate . " rank " . ++$i;
}

// Find the rank of specific user:
echo array_search('matt', array_keys($sort)) + 1;
```

Comment: I’ve implemented as such; 
   $size = $num_rows;
    $p = 0;
 
    while($p < $size)  
    { 
      $user[$p] = array("user" => $user[$p]); 
      $scanrate[$p] = array ("data" => $scanrate[$p]);
      $p++; 
    } 
 
    $sort = array_combine($user, $scanrate);

However I seem to be having a further problem of the array $sort is false, I assume I’ve done something wrong here, however I’m not sure what.

Comment: If you check the manual: http://php.net/array_combine you can see that array_combine takes the first array as keys and second one as values and also check the array types, they should be one dimensional. I don't understand what you're trying to do with that while loop, you're adding a dimension to the array which breaks the array_combine function. Try to get a list (array) of users and a list of scanrates, do the sorting with that structure (because otherwise the functions don't work correctly) and finally alter the structure of the array if you need to.